# How could one split a comma delimited string while ignoring the commas which are in braces?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string which represents the attributes of a function:

`str = "'MyCommunities', null, {'viewAllLink':'https://cpkornferrybruceapidev.azurewebsites.net', 'clientId':'078c49af-bb40-44c3-a685-539a84cc5de7', 'subscriptionId':'64fc6f58-2a67-472b-b57f-f0f5441e7992'}"`

There are 3 attributes: `My Communities`, `null`, `{...}`

I would like to split the string into array containing these 3 values but without splitting the object literal.

I believe I need to construct a regular expression which would allow me to `str.split(//)` however I am not able to get the 3 attributes which I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: then do it with space. **str.split(/\ /)**

Comment: Do you have nested braces?

Comment: what about replace `'` to `"`, then `JSON.parse('['+str+']')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If be sure the string doesn't have extra `'` in the value of each element, I think one quick way is treat it as one JSON string, then pull out the element you need.

The codes are like below:

```js
let str = "'MyCommunities', null, {'viewAllLink':'https://cpkornferrybruceapidev.azurewebsites.net', 'clientId':'078c49af-bb40-44c3-a685-539a84cc5de7', 'subscriptionId':'64fc6f58-2a67-472b-b57f-f0f5441e7992'}"

console.log(JSON.parse('[' + str.replace(/'/g, '"') +']'))
```

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have nested braces and if comma is always before `{`, then you can do this:

```
var re = /(\{[^}]+\})/;
var result = [];
str.split(re).forEach(function(part) {
  if (part.match(re) {
     result.push(part);
  } else {
     var parts = part.split(',').map((x) => x.trim()).filter(Boolean);
     result = result.concat(parts);
  }
});
```

if you have something before braces or if braces are nested you will need more compicated parser.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to find a different way to get the string formatted coming into your system. If that is not feasible, you can do the following regex (*note: it is super fragile*):

```
/\,(?![^{]*})/
```

and get the groupings like so:

```
list = str.split(/\,(?![^{]*})/)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second `limit` parameter of `split()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) to stop cutting before the object literal:

```js
var str = "'MyCommunities', null, {'viewAllLink':'https://cpkornferrybruceapidev.azurewebsites.net', 'clientId':'078c49af-bb40-44c3-a685-539a84cc5de7', 'subscriptionId':'64fc6f58-2a67-472b-b57f-f0f5441e7992'}";

console.log(str.split(', ', 3));
```